# Browsers don't detect SSL certificate

Tags: nginx, certbot

I have Nginx 1.20 with certbot certificate but the browsers detect problems. Firefox return SSL_ERROR_RX_RECORD_TOO_LONG and Chrome ERR_SSL_PROTOCOL_ERROR. what did I do wrong?. This is my server block:

```html
server {
    listen 443;

    server_name test.com;

    ssl_certificate /etc/letsencrypt/live/test.com/fullchain.pem;
    ssl_certificate_key /etc/letsencrypt/live/test.com/privkey.pem;

    root /var/www/test.com;
    index index.php index.html index.htm;

    client_max_body_size 20M;

    location = /favicon.ico {
         log_not_found off;
         access_log off;
    }

    location = /robots.txt {
        allow all;
        log_not_found off;
        access_log off;
    }

    location / {
        try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?$args;
    }

    location ~ \.php$ {
        fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php/php7.4-fpm.sock;
        fastcgi_index index.php;
        fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
        include fastcgi_params;
    }
}
```

This is the curl response.

```html
* ALPN, offering h2
* ALPN, offering http/1.1
* successfully set certificate verify locations:
*   CAfile: /etc/ssl/certs/ca-certificates.crt
  CApath: /etc/ssl/certs
* TLSv1.3 (OUT), TLS handshake, Client hello (1):
* error:1408F10B:SSL routines:ssl3_get_record:wrong version number
* Closing connection 0
curl: (35) error:1408F10B:SSL routines:ssl3_get_record:wrong version number
```

Comment: Use the CLI tool *curl* with the debug option -v and post the command and output in your question.

Comment: Thanks. @JohnHanley

* ALPN, offering h2
* ALPN, offering http/1.1
* successfully set certificate verify locations:
*   CAfile: /etc/ssl/certs/ca-certificates.crt
  CApath: /etc/ssl/certs
* TLSv1.3 (OUT), TLS handshake, Client hello (1):
* error:1408F10B:SSL routines:ssl3_get_record:wrong version number
* Closing connection 0
curl: (35) error:1408F10B:SSL routines:ssl3_get_record:wrong version number

Comment: Please put the requested information in your question correctly formatted.

Comment: @JohnHanley Done.

Comment: The error message **wrong version number** typically means the client is connecting via HTTPS and the server is not providing TLS. You did not show the command, so I do not know which port you connected to. Try changing this line **listen 443;** to **listen 443 ssl;**.

Comment: When i try change to listen 443 ssl nginx return the following error: "nginx: [emerg] no "ssl_certificate" is defined for the "listen ... ssl" directive"

Comment: You are getting close to defining the problem. Double-check the certificates, the certificate configuration, etc.